How to switch between two Windows Forms in C#
I'm new to Winforms. I'm using VS2022 and .NET 6 to create a Winforms app.
I created two forms (loginForm and MainForm). I'm trying to use the loginForm to protect data in MainForm. When user logs in, the loginForm should be hidden and show MainForm, so user can perform some actions.
When user finishes his actions, he should click logout, which shows the loginForm again, and hides the MainForm. Please help

The first part of this post may be helpful (it's VB.NET, but the concepts are the same for C#).

Have you considered using WPF instead of Windows Forms?

I can switch to WPF if it easier to implement my requrements using WPF, even I never did WPF before

It's just more modern, that's all. WinForms was never going to be in .net core but MS hammed it in under pressure from the world and it's a bit bug-ridden and unloved of a design experience. I still use framework 4.8 for winforms

Show the code you have written for flip flopping between these forms. It should be a trivial operation of hiding the current form and showing the intended one, probably easiest using the Application.OpenForms collections

You could try the example below.
I tested the following steps and it works.
click loginin -> show MainForm -> Click Hide MainForm -> show  LoginForm->click login out  -> then click loginin again -> show  previously-hidden MainForm
 internal static class Program
 {
     
     private static Form1 mainForm;
     private static LoginForm loginForm;

     [STAThread]
     static void Main()
     {
         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

         mainForm = new Form1();
         loginForm = new LoginForm();

         loginForm.Login += LoginForm_Login;
         loginForm.Logout += LoginForm_Logout;

         loginForm.Show();
        

         mainForm.Invisible += MainForm_FormInvisible;
         Application.Run();

     }
    
     private static void MainForm_FormInvisible(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         mainForm.Hide();
         loginForm.Show();
     }
     private static void LoginForm_Login(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         
         
         loginForm.Hide();
         if (mainForm.IsDisposed)
         {
             mainForm = new Form1();
         }
         mainForm.Show();
     }

     private static void LoginForm_Logout(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       
         mainForm.Hide();
         loginForm.Show();
     }
 }


LoginForm(loginbutton and logout button):

 public partial class LoginForm : Form
 {
     
     public event EventHandler Login;
     public event EventHandler Logout;

     public LoginForm()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
     private void OnLogin()
     {
         Login?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
     }
     private void OnLogout()
     {
         Logout?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
     }
  
     private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {  
         OnLogin();
     }
     private void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         OnLogout();
     }

//exit button

 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Application.Exit();
 }

 }


MainForm((textbox and Hide button)):
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
    
     public event EventHandler Invisible;
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         OnHide();
     }
     private void OnHide()
     {
         Invisible?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
     }

 }


Thanks a lot! It works perfectly. However, If I change all show() to showDialog(). Click button on MainForm doesn't work anymore(MainForm doesn't disappear). Could you help try the same?

In the end, I need another button(eg. "cancel") on LoginForm, clicking it should shutdown the app.

I updated the cancel button on the LoginForm in my answer. This cannot be achieved if all displays are set to showdialog. If you change all instances of Show() to ShowDialog() in  code, it will cause the LoginForm to be displayed modally. In a modal dialog, execution is paused in the caller until the dialog is closed.
In your scenario, this would cause the MainForm to not disappear when the "Hide" button is clicked because the code execution in the MainForm will not continue until the LoginForm is closed.

You can try this:
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
    while (true)
    {
        var dlg = new LoginForm();
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
        else if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Abort)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

and in LoginForm, provide two results
for success login: this.DialogResult=DiaglogResult.OK;
for exiting application: this.DialogResult=DiaglogResult.Abort;

Thanks for help. I want the two forms to be created when the app starts and stay (only one form show itself). After logout (The mainform is still running even its invisible), when login again, I just want hide loginform and show the previously-hidden mainform(NOT create another mainform instance)

Your code seems almost correct for switching between two Windows Forms in C#. However, there's a mistake in the Form2 class where you're creating an instance of Form1 instead of Form2 when switching back to Form1.
Here's the corrected version of your code:
namespace SwitchBetweenWinfomToWinfomApp
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
            // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}

namespace SwitchBetweenWinfomToWinfomApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void btnSwitchToForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create an instance of Form2
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            
            // Show Form2
            form2.Show();
            
            // Hide the current form (Form1)
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}

namespace SwitchBetweenWinfomToWinfomApp
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void btnSwitchToForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create an instance of Form1
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            
            // Show Form1
            form1.Show();
            
            // Hide the current form (Form2)
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}




I don't want to create new instance of the forms each time when I click button on one of the two forms. Clicking button on one form just hide the current one and switch to the existing invisible form of the other type

Please sort your code markers out, this post is a mess. Either indent all code 4 spaces or place 3 backticks at the start and end of the code ```
